# Why am I getting a black line around my 32-bit context in Cocos2D?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm having an issue with rendering my own sprites in Cocos2D. If I create a context, even with supposedly a premultiplied alpha, I get black artefacts. The following code should produce a completely white circle:

```
- (void)renderTest
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0);

    unsigned char *data = calloc((int)rect.size.width * (int)rect.size.height, 4);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, (int)rect.size.width, (int)rect.size.height, 8, (int)rect.size.width*4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextAddArc(context, rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2, rect.size.width * 0.4, 0.0, 2 * M_PI, 0);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithData:data pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 pixelsWide:rect.size.width pixelsHigh:rect.size.height contentSize:rect.size];

    self.texture = tex;
    self.textureRect = rect;

    free(data);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}
```

When placed on a white background, this should be invisible. However, in reality I get this:

[image]

If I do exactly the same thing in UIKit using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` then it works flawlessly without the black hairline.

Can anyone please tell me how to get it to render the alpha channel without dodgy artefacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like rendering is done with a `glBlendFunc` that is not suitable for premultiplied colors.

There are two (and a half) options to fix this:

1. Set the blend function to `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`. I have no idea about this Cocos2D thing and if you can influence the blend function or tell it otherwise to use premultiplied colors.
2. Don't use premultiplied colors in your bitmap context. I'm not sure if the resulting pixel format is supported on iOS, though.
3. If everything is white you could just set the RGB parts of the `data` to 0xFFFFFF and just leave the alpha in place before creating the texture.

Edit: Here's code that paint's everything in your texture white:

```
uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t *)data;
void *end = data + CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context) * CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context);
while (ptr != end)
    *ptr++ |= 0xffffff; // or 0xffffff00, depending on endianess and pixel format in context
```

Comment: Point #1 works as `self.blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA};` except for the fact it doesn't play nicely with opacity levels. Point #2 I'm not sure if there is a non-premultiplied 32-bit mode available on iOS. Point #3 I'm going to try next!

Comment: Point #3 works great, even with opacity levels and fade animations, so I'm going to go with that. I guess if I change the RGB value to a custom text colour parameter then I've covered myself if I need to render text in different colours. Thanks!